# How to get a primary key from a model without querying the DB once I've added the model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

*This is all refactorable, so if there's a better way to approach the situation overall, let me know. This got wordy really quick, sorry.*

---

I'm creating a movie database, and I've got 3 tables, `Movies`, `Genres` and `MovieToGenre`. I've created the `Genre` table, and to populate the `MtG` table, I'm trying to associate a `genre_id` with a `movie_id`, which is a one-to-many relationship, I think, so it'll have something like the following in it

```
movie_id | genre_id
1    56
1    786
2    232
2    656
```

But my issue is that in order to fill that table, I need the `movie_id` from the `Movie` model. I assumed that  once I've added the `Movie` to the `Movies` table, that the model would retroactively update its `movie_id` property, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as the `MovieToGenre` table gets populated with `movie_id`'s  equalling 0, the default value.  The `Movies` table is using the proper `movie_id` so it's a matter of telling my `FillMovieToGenre` method which movie has what `movie_id`.

The general process I'm using is the following loop:

1. Create `Movie` instance, not setting the `movie_id`, since MVC
   chooses one itself

   a. `movie = new Movie(data1, data2)`
2. Add `Movie` instance to table

   a.  `db.Movies.Add(movie)`
3. Use the last `Movie` instance's `movie_id`  in a
   `FillMovieToGenreTable()` method.

   a. `FillMtGTable(movie)` But at this point, the movie does not contain the non-default `movie_id` and so the `MtG` table is filled with `movie_id = 0`, where it should be `movie_id = 1231` etc.
4. GOTO 1.

**tl;dr Possible to get a primary key for a recently added model? Seems like making a new query would be a bad idea, since I'm looping over all the movies I need to add, and that new query would slow the process down, I'd think.**

edited in the relevant parts of the `Movie` class

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int movie_ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
 }

public class Genre
{
    [DisplayName("Genre ID")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int genre_ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Genre")]
    public string genre_string { get; set; }
}

public class MovieToGenre
{

[Key]
    public int movie_to_genre_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual int movie_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual int genre_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What data framework are you using? Try to retag your question with the relevant framework, and remove the unrelated tags.

Comment: Are you suggesting EF Code First, or the type of SQL server? The code is in C#, the framework is ASP.NET MVC4 and it's some variant of SQL. I'll make the changes for sure, just want to know what you mean exactly.

Comment: I mean the framework you're using for your data access layer - if you're using EF Code First, then that will be it. You can imagine that this question would be relevant to anyone using EF Code First (or whatever you use), regardless of whether using ASP.NET MVC, or C#, or even potentially SQL. It's a question about EF... right?

Comment: Can you show us your model classes (in case you are using EF)?

Comment: @LukasKabrt Edited in the models.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst removed `SQL` tag, updated the `MVC` tag and added the `EF` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF after you save changes in other words after you run

```
db.Movies.Add(movie)
db.SaveChanges();
```

EF should automatically give you the populated ID

```
int movie_id=movie.movie_id;
```

Comment: I'm saving all the changes afters I've added them all in, would saving the changes after every `Add` slow down the process significantly? So far it's about 25 minutes to add 55k rows. Not bad in the grand scheme, but I'd like to keep it as low as possible.

Comment: It better to save after every add takes less time and less noticable to user

Comment: Alright, I went with this, and the model was updated. I also had to set a `DatabaseGenerated` option to `Identity` because it changed either `movie_id` or `movie_to_genre_id` to 0 depending on some random (from my POV, I don't understand why) variables. I'll just deal with the speed loss. Thanks.